# Is it possible to determine user profile using Chrome Extension API?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to determine which user profile is logged in Chrome from my custom extension using Chrome API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no Chrome-API for that, the best (any only) way is to use oAuth:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2

**UPDATE:**

Yesterday Google has published news about the Identity API at the Chromium blog.
**The Identity API may only work with packaged Apps!**

> **Identity API**
>
> The Identity API allows packaged apps to authenticate users securely
>   using OAuth 2.0 without the user having to provide a username and
>   password directly to the app. The Identity API supports authentication
>   using Google Accounts as well as third party providers such as GitHub
>   and Foursquare.
>
> The Identity API also gives packaged apps secure access to Google APIs
>   such as Google+, Calendar and Drive. As an example, Google Keep uses
>   the Identity API to authenticate users as well as to call the Google
>   Drive API to save notes to Drive. The Identity API uses a webview
>   based UI to show the OAuth consent dialog and when the Google+ API
>   scope is used, it allows users to control who can see their activity
>   on the app.

[image]

Source: http://blog.chromium.org/2013/07/richer-access-to-google-services-and.html
Documentation at developer.chrome.com: https://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/app_identity.html

Comment: I edited the answer ;)
Just [upvote/mark as solution] my answer if I solved your question.

Comment: I must be missing something. I think that OAuth2 applies for gmail account, right? And it's not connected with browser's user profile: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142059?hl=en

Comment: You're right but its your only chance. As long as I know there is NO API for accessing the Chrome profile data.

Comment: oh..that's sad=( Thanks anyway

Comment: I know, I had the same problem more than a year ago.

Comment: Sign in with Google using oAuth :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's possible to do so, consider writing a [Chrome packaged app](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) instead. The [Identity API](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/experimental.identity.html) will give you the information you need.

Comment: The link to the Chrome packaged app documentation has moved or removed. Can you update your answer?