# Pulling Chrome profiles in order with python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to pull the Chrome profiles and do the same for all of them, can you help me? How do I pull multiple Chrome profiles and process them one after the other?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to determine user profile using Chrome Extension API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046714/is-it-possible-to-determine-user-profile-using-chrome-extension-api)

Comment: What's you specific question ? Where to find them, how to process, ... ?

Comment: I want to open multiple chrome profiles and repeat the same process on all of them..